# file copy error with Maven

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven

i want to copie file compared my profiles identifier.

***I launch this command:***

```
mvn -Pprod install
```

***I have this error:***

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4:copy-resources
>   (copy-web.xml) on proj ect apex: Execution copy-web.xml of goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4:copy-resources
>   failed: base dir
>   D:\workspace\apex\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.prod.xml is not a
>   directory -> [Help 1]

***My pom.xml:***

```
    <properties>
        <webXmlFile>web.xml</webXmlFile>
        <profileVersion>defaultVersion</profileVersion>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <profileVersion>DEV</profileVersion>
                <webXmlFile>web.dev.xml</webXmlFile>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>preprod</id>
            <properties>
                <profileVersion>PREPROD</profileVersion>
                <webXmlFile>web.preprod.xml</webXmlFile>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <profileVersion>PROD</profileVersion>
                <webXmlFile>web.prod.xml</webXmlFile>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

<build>
        <finalName>app-${project.version}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-web.xml</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/WEB-INF</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/${webXmlFile}</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        ...
    ...
...
```

Comment: the "is not a directory" message is quite clear to me : ) in the resources you passed a file as a directory, so it is complaining (for whatever it would be worth for, I'm not the downvoter)

Comment: @A.DiMatteo yes it's clear for me but how can pass my file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use include for files:

```
                            <resource>
                                <directory>/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/</directory>
                               <includes>
                                <include> ${webXmlFile}</include>
                               </includes>
                            </resource>
```